# Iterating through multiple lists

Tags: java, list, collections

I have two seperate lists from a DTO i created, the two lists are containing different set of data i.e in first list lets say there are some 'userloginname' along with 2nd last updated 'status'.
In the 2nd List i have  'userloginname' with all the status record(not just the 2nd last updated status).

Is this possible if want to take each 'userloginname' from List1 and compare with each 'userloginname' in the list2 with some condition.?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm misunderstanding, but how about something like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < list1.size() ; i++) {
    // Do something with "list1.get(i)" and "list2.get(i)"
}
```

With this you can compare items at a given index in `list1` with items at the corresponding index in `list2`. If you want to compare every `list1` member with every other `list2` member, you could do something like:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < list1.size() ; i++)
    for (int j = 0 ; j < list2.size() ; j++) {
        // Do something with "list1.get(i)" and "list2.get(j)"
    }
```

Comment: this should do, altho the 2 lists would need to have the same length.

Comment: but the list is having two values stored in it i.e. loginname and status so what would list1.get(i) return?

Answer (score 0):

Convert one of the lists to a map using 'userloginname' as a key.

```
List<LastStatusRecord> lastStatusRecords = dto.getLastStatusRecords();
List<StatusRecord> statusRecords = dto.getStatusRecords();

Map<String, FullRecord> statusRecordIndex = new HashMap<String, StatusRecord>();
for (StatusRecord statusRecord : statusRecords) {
  statusRecordIndex.put(statusRecord.getUserLoginName(), statusRecord);
}
for (LastStatusRecord lastStatusRecord : lastStatusRecords) {
  StatusRecord statusRecord = statusRecordIndex.get(lastStatusRecord.getUserLoginName());
  // place the condition here
}
```